# Excel formula semicolon vs comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why do some people use commas to separate params in the formulas and some use semicolons?

It's all about the region where you live.

Comment: No, because in this question the source of the formula is vba and for the answer: they are not setting the separator global, for the whole os (user i think)

Comment: They are just replacing the separators

Comment: Does it apply to Mac OS too?

Comment: I don't really know but maybe you can find more about it under this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/line-separator-comma-semicolon-in-excel-2016-for/7db1b1a0-0300-44ba-ab9b-35d1c40159c6

Comment: It was what is called a rhetorical question... I know about it and it is due to the systems settings, based on language choices, currency and date choices.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about a tiny setting in Windows.
The default setting may be dependent on your region.

---

If you want to change it:

1. go to region settings:

   - using Win+R and type `intl.cpl`
   - same using Windows search/startmenu (`intl.cpl`)
   - Windows settings -> Time & Language -> Region & Language -> Under "Related Settings": Additional date, time & regional settings -> Under "Region": Change location
2. Additional settings
3. **List separator** is the field you are looking for

Comment: The answer is kind of incomplete without references to `Options >> Advanced (Editing Options) >> Use System Separators` and `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`, (and who knows what). Study those and improve your answer (possibly question, too).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Excel must uniquely identifying the character that separates parameters. If the decimal point is comma you cannot use this also to separate parameters, so semicolon is used.